# Is it possible to get a log of changing bundles statuses?

Tags: osgi, bundle

I use **osgi console**. The command `ss` very usefull, but I want to observe changes in the status of each of the bundles for debug. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

**Using LogService**

See the chapter *101.6.1 Bundle Event Mapping* under chapter *101 Log Service Specification* in OSGi Compendium specification:

In short: If there is a [LogService](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/log/LogService.html) implementation in the container, each Bundle and Service event is logged. The logged records can be read with [LogReaderService](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/log/LogReaderService.html). Equinox has a built-in implementation, in Felix I normally use the one [implemented by Felix](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.felix%7Corg.apache.felix.log%7C1.0.1%7Cbundle).

After you have a LogService implementation in your container, you should somehow achieve that the results are written to the console. There are several ways here as well. One I can recommend is the following:

- Install one of the slf4j implementation bundles (e.g.: [slf4j-simple](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.slf4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22slf4j-simple%22) that simply logs everything to the standard output) together with [slf4j-api](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.slf4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22slf4j-api%22)
- Install Everit [Loglistener To SLF4J](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22org.everit.osgi.loglistener.slf4j%22) that forwards every Log entries to SLF4J API. SLF4J will write than the entries to the console

**Implementing a BundleListener**

You can catch all live bundle events with a [BundleListener](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleListener.html)

**Implementing a BundleTracker**

You can implement a [BundleTracker](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/BundleTracker.html) where you can catch all of the Bundle events. In that case you will get the last events of the installed bundles (at least installed) that happened before opening your tracker, too.

Comment: I think you mean either use a LogReaderService to observe LogEntrys for BundleEvents or use a BundleTracker to track bundle state changes. You can also just register a BundleListener to receive BundleEvents.

Comment: Yes I meant that. I somehow switched from Bundles to Services in mind during writing the answer :). I fixed that now.

Comment: I still think you need to change the answer to use a LogReaderService rather than LogService. LogService is for making LogEntrys. LogReaderService is for observing LogEntrys which is the issue at hand here. So while you will need a LogService Specification implementation, the code will need to use the LogReaderService to observe the LogEntrys for bundle state changes.

Comment: Yes, I concentrated on the issue of "ServiceTracker instead of BundleTracker" in the last edit. Edited again. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use [Byteman](http://byteman.jboss.org/). It would be something like this:

```
####################################################

RULE Bundle state change
CLASS org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle
METHOD beginStateChange()
IF TRUE
DO
System.out.println("[STATE CHANGE] " + $this.getBundle() + " > " + $this.getBundle().getState());
ENDRULE

####################################################

RULE Bundle complete state change
CLASS org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle
METHOD completeStateChange()
AT EXIT
IF TRUE
DO
System.out.println("[COMPLETE STATE CHANGE] " + $this.getBundle() + " > " + $this.getBundle().getState());
ENDRULE
```